# Take photo to buffer/array Windows universal app c#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

Please help me.
I'm trying to get photo from camera to buffer in order to make image processing later.
I found that I should use MediaCapture element to work with camera, but I didn't find how to save frame into buffer.

Comment: I dont think you can save it to a buffer instead of disk.  Besides on a phone  you might get an out of memory exception trying to load the image into a buffer

Answer (score 1):

You can save frame to bitmap and process it later. Here is the [OCR sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/OCR) that provided by Microsoft on GitHub:

```
// Create the video frame to request a SoftwareBitmap preview frame.
var videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, videoFrameWidth, videoFrameHeight);

// Capture the preview frame.
using (var currentFrame = await mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame))
{
  // Collect the resulting frame.
  SoftwareBitmap bitmap = currentFrame.SoftwareBitmap;
  ...
  var ocrResult = await ocrEngine.RecognizeAsync(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one more example: CaptureElement https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraManualControls

Saving the photo:

```
 private async Task TakePhotoAsync()
     {
          var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

            try
            {

                await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);

                var photoOrientation = ConvertOrientationToPhotoOrientation(GetCameraOrientation());

                await ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(stream, photoOrientation);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

      }
```